# How to get Locked Balance of a particular account with a particular LockIdentifier in a pallet?

Tags: balances, lockable-currency, locked-balance

In a pallet I have used `set_lock()` with a own `LockIdentifier` for that pallet. Now I need to check the locked balance of an account with that `LockIdentifier` and not the global locked amount. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to query the [lock balance](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#locksaccountid32-vecpalletbalancesbalancelock) in the pallet_balances. On there you can see the identifier of the lock.

Query this storage ([see code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L449)):

```rs
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn locks)]
    pub type Locks<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        WeakBoundedVec<BalanceLock<T::Balance>, T::MaxLocks>,
        ValueQuery,
    >;
```

And there you can filter using the `LockIdentifier` that you want with the field id.

```rs
/// A single lock on a balance. There can be many of these on an account and they "overlap", so the
/// same balance is frozen by multiple locks.
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, RuntimeDebug, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct BalanceLock<Balance> {
    /// An identifier for this lock. Only one lock may be in existence for each identifier.
    pub id: LockIdentifier,
    /// The amount which the free balance may not drop below when this lock is in effect.
    pub amount: Balance,
    /// If true, then the lock remains in effect even for payment of transaction fees.
    pub reasons: Reasons,
}
```

Comment: so for this we need to tightly couple pallet-balances to my pallet ?

Comment: If you want this information inside your pallet you will have to query another pallet yes. Another option might be keep track (Adding a storage) in your pallet of all the funds you are locking